# is it possible to mapping Alt-hjkl in Insert mode?

Tags: vim, vi

before describing my problem,  I'd list the env. applications here:

```
OS:linux 2.6.37-ARCH  (archlinux i686)
vim: 7.2.436
Terminal emulator: urxvt (with 256colors patch)

kent$ echo $TERM
rxvt-256color

screen: Screen version 4.00.03 (FAU) 23-Oct-06
```

I run vim in terminal. I want to move cursor in INSERT mode by pressing ALT-hjkl, after the cursor moved, stay in INSERT mode, so that I could continue typing words.

articles I found:

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_fast_keycodes_in_terminal_Vim

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Get_Alt_key_to_work_in_terminal

what I tried:

in .vimrc do a keyCode mapping with ttimeoutlen=50 like this: ( only alt-j mapping was pasted as example):

```
set timeout ttimeoutlen=50
set <F13>=^[j  "ctrl-v alt-j
imap <F13> <down>
```

with this conf, moving cursor in INSERT mode was ok. If I press `<ESC>` and j. Vim brings me back to insert Mode. I don't know why the `ttimeoutlen=50` didn't work.

also tried:

```
set timeout ttimeoutlen=50
set <M-j>=^[j
```

With this setting, when I pressed ALT-j, a "e" with an accent mark was typed.

Can you guys give me any hints how should I map the ALT-hjkl in terminal ?

Thanks in advance

Kent

Answer (score 29):

It's easier to map what your key combination does. `Alt+something` generally results in a character, differently from `Ctrl+something`.

For example, on my Mac `Alt` plus `hjkl` generates `˙∆˚¬`. So:

```
imap ˙ <Left>
imap ∆ <Down>
imap ˚ <Up>
imap ¬ <Right>
```

would do it.

Comment: if i type ctrl-v alt-h,j,k,l in INSERT mode with my urxvt terminal. I got ^[j ^[h ^[k ^[l

Comment: @Kent, not typing ctrl-v before, if you press only alt+h, alt+j, alt+k and alt+l, what's the output?

Comment: if I type alt-j for example,  in INSERT mode (under terminal), vim will be changed into Normal Mode, and cursor will move one line down. this because, in terminal "ALT-*" terminal keycode is ^[*, ^[ is <ESC> if we talk about vim keycode.

Comment: @Kent, I think I understand it correctly now. Searching over the internet, I've found messages in a Yahoo! Group describing the same problem. You may want to have a look on the other messages also, but the one that contains the solution (actually 2 of them!) is here: http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/vim/message/55886 Basically, you want to put a `<C-V>` in the mapping or set `<M-*>` to `<C-V><alt-*>`. I hope it works!

Comment: I have tried the 'solutions' there before I posted the question. they didn't work by me... :( but thanks anyway.

Comment: @Kent, I'm sorry, but my resources ended. I hope you can find the solution! Once you do so, please post it here as an answer so we can have it registered. Regards

Comment: For French people (with a mac AZERTY keyboard), the corresponding keys are ÌÏÈ¬

Comment: For anyone else that comes across this, for use with a mac, you are overall better off just making alt work as alt should. For terminal.app: settings -> keyboard -> "use option as meta". For iterm: settings -> profile -> your profile -> keys -> set option to "+Esc"

Comment: Do you know to make an analogous solution work in tmux? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35344479/makikng-alt-h-switch-to-the-left-pane-in-tmux for a question I just asked that uses your advice.

Answer (score 15):

**For arrow keys:**

Start by viewing the key code your terminal is sending to vim:

```
$ sed -n l
^[[1;9D
```

In the above example, i ran the sed command and pressed <kbd>Alt + Left</kbd>.

The `^[[1;9D` is the escaped sequence being sent to vim, so we can user that for our mapping.

Add this to your .vimrc

```
map <Esc>[1;9D :tabn<CR>
```

Now we can cycle through vim tabs by using <kbd>Alt + Left</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, it works for me. BTW, in cygwin ALT+Left  output is \033[1;3D$, here \033 is <Esc>, and we need to remove the '$'

Comment: Had to use this approach with osx mavericks / iTerm / Vim 7.4. Works like a champ- thanks for the alternate solution.

Comment: Do you know to make an analogous solution work in tmux? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35344479/makikng-alt-h-switch-to-the-left-pane-in-tmux for a question I just asked that uses your advice.

Comment: @George let me check with a friend he might have the answer

Comment: @lfender6445: If this were real life, I would offer you a beer :)