# How to Alt-hjkl to move cursor stay in insert mode in vim?

Tags: vim

In insert mode alt-hjkl will go to normal mode, i dont want.

I want alt-hjkl move the cursor and stay in insert mode.

So,try add this to vimrc but it doesn't work.

> noremap! < A-h >   < left >
>
> noremap! < A-j > < down >
>
> noremap! < A-k > < up >
>
> noremap! < A-l > < right >

any ideas ? :)

Comment: If that's exactly how you've written it, you've got the syntax (spacing) wrong. Read `:h key-notation` to learn how to do it right.

Comment: if you meant gvim, it is easy... if in terminal.... I was trying to achieve the same, but finally gave up. (`urxvt` terminal)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379837/is-it-possible-to-mapping-alt-hjkl-in-insert-mode

Answer (score 1):

Correct usage is:

```
inoremap <A-h> <left>
inoremap <A-j> <down>
inoremap <A-k> <up>
inoremap <A-l> <right>
```

Comment: does this work for terminal vim too? :)  see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379837/is-it-possible-to-mapping-alt-hjkl-in-insert-mode

Comment: ah, you're right...oh well, the Alt key is always problematic, I just avoid it...they seem to be working in the terminal on Windows though :)

Answer (score 0):

I use `xmodmap` to achieve such behavior, but I use <kbd>Caps</kbd> instead of <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

see [solution](https://superuser.com/questions/96299/mapping-superhjkl-to-arrow-keys-under-x/1076823#1076823) on Superuser.

Comment: The question regards vim, which is not an X application. Why would using xmodmap be relevant?

Comment: Good Point. My suggestion is more of a workaround then a solution. However, it works fine for my Linux, where all my applications are running in X. (also vim started in Terminal-emulator)

Also at the point I discovered for my self, that I could use hjkl-movement in any application, I didn't want to go back. And maybe the OP wants to go there next.