# Make Alt + h switch to the left pane in Tmux

Tags: tmux

I'm trying to make <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>h</kbd> switch to the left pane in Tmux. This does not work:

```
bind -n M-h select-pane -L
```

Pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>h</kbd> in `cat` generates the following output in my terminal:

```
$ cat
^[h
```

That is, it looks like <kbd>Alt</kbd> generates `^[` in my terminal. So, in my Tmux configuration, I have also tried this binding:

```
bind -n ^[h select-pane -L
```

I have made "^[" both a literal two character string (i.e., "^" + "[") as well as the special "^[" character you can access in Vim. Neither work.

How to solve this problem?

**EDIT:** I'm primarily using xfce4-terminal as my terminal emulator, but I've tried using gnome-terminal as well as xterm, and the problem persists.

Comment: what terminal emulator are you using?

Comment: @lfender6445, I edited my question above to answer your question.

Answer (score 3):

Actually the secret is how you enter `^[` ;-)

I assume you want to edit your .vimrc

```
vim ~/.vimrc
```

- navigate to the correct position
- press <kbd>i</kbd>
- press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd>
- press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>[</kbd> (on a german keyboard I have to press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>altgr</kbd>-<kbd>8</kbd> because <kbd>altgr</kbd>-<kbd>8</kbd> is `[`)

After that you should have the escape sequence generated required to write the binding.