# Vim: set 'cursor' keys hjkl to wasd

Tags: linux, vim, vi, vim-plugin

I admit that I'm not an expert `vim` user so forgive me not providing previous attempts!

I wish to overwrite/remap the basic `vi`/`vim` (and `gvim`) "cursor keys" **hjkl** to the ordinary "gamer layout" **wasd** (w-up, a-left, s-down, d-right). Moreover: I know that "w", "a", "s" and "d" are important keys in `vim` so I came up with the idea to remap **hjkl** to **ALT + wasd**.

Have to configure .vimrc? Or is there some plugin? Can you help me?

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to change your [identical question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/293753/vim-set-cursor-keys-hjkl-to-wasd) at the Unix Site but I assume you meant ALT.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers: thanks, yes I meant ALT. Edited at Unix Site.

Comment: What do you see when you open a terminal, run the 'cat' command, and enter the following keypresses in sequence: `Alt-w`, `Alt-a`, `Alt-s`, and `Alt-d`?

Comment: @zarak: `^[w` `^[a` `^[s` and `^[d`

Answer (score 4):

Map your Alt + aswd to hjkl; in your `.vimrc`

```
noremap <A-a> h
noremap <A-s> j
noremap <A-w> k
noremap <A-d> l
```

Comment: Would this work with the Alt key? I think it suffers from the problem described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379837/is-it-possible-to-mapping-alt-hjkl-in-insert-mode).

Comment: @zarak, Tanx, Maybe BUT That's a separate issue. Its totally terminal based! @Tom Solid, you should examine what escaped sequence is being sent to vim when you for example pressing `ALT + a`, use the refrences that zarak is introduced.

Answer (score 2):

According to [zarak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5912399/zarak)'s and [dNitro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5048383/dnitro)'s solutions, in my case adding

```
noremap <Esc>a h
noremap <Esc>s j
noremap <Esc>w k
noremap <Esc>d l
```

to `.vimrc` solved the problem.

---

Because in my case

```
cat
ALT-w
ALT-a
ALT-s
ATL-d
```

resulted **^]w** **^]a** **^]s** and **^]d**.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I think adding this to your .vimrc should do the trick.

```
noremap ^[a h
noremap ^[s j
noremap ^[w k
noremap ^[d l
```

Comment: Ah I misunderstood your question. dNitro's solution should work then, if you type in the characters your terminal generates.