# Vim: set 'cursor' keys hjkl to wasd also in normal and insert mode

Tags: vim, vi

I have asked a [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38182952/vim-set-cursor-keys-hjkl-to-wasd/38184185?noredirect=1#comment63794517_38184185) about what should I add to `.vimrc` to map **ALT + a** to "h"; **ALT + s** to "j" and so on. The solution is adding the following to `.vimrc`:

```
noremap <Esc>a h
noremap <Esc>s j
noremap <Esc>w k
noremap <Esc>d l
```

Now, my problem is, that this solution does not work in `INSERT mode` (but works in `NORMAL mode`). Using `imap` results like typing h,j,k,l, `iunmap` results error.

How to set `.vimrc` to make **ALT + wasd** works like **hjkl** "cursor keys" also in `INSERT mode`?

Comment: Learn Vim before wasting too much time in the customization aisle of your local department store.

Comment: Notice you are using `noremap` here, not `map`. Did you try `inoremap` instead of `imap`? `noremap` is only effective in modes `n`, `v`, `o`, not in `i` (insert) mode.

Answer (score 1):

To make it work in insert mode you could just add this to your `.vimrc`

```
inoremap <esc>a <left>
inoremap <esc>d <right>
inoremap <esc>w <up>
inoremap <esc>s <down>
```

You have to be careful with this though, because this may conflict with other commands when you're switching out of insert mode. When you for instance want to delete the line you're currently editing, you could do `<esc>dd`, but with these keybindings you would add a `d` after the next character.